# How to specify the version in bower override?

Tags: version-control, bower, tinymce-4

this is a part of my bower.json:

```
"overrides": {
  "tinymce-dist": {
    "main": [
      "tinymce.js",
      "themes/modern/theme.js",
      "plugins/*/plugin.js"
    ]
  }
},
```

For the reason of [this Issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce/issues/264), I want to specify the version of tinymce-dist to 4.3.12. But how does it work? Something like adding `"version": "4.3.12"` doesn't work.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Type the command in the project root. Remove tinymce-dist first and reinstall it in version 4.3.12. Then you solve the problem.

```
$ bower uninstall --save tinymce-dist
$ bower install --save tinymce-dist#4.3.12
```

---

[Refer to the doc](https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files/blob/98f370f8791087345613eaeb301cea3b7d876dbb/README.md#overrides-options),your bower.json should adds the dependency specification. The command above do the jobs for you.

```
"dependencies": {
    "tinymce-dist": "4.3.12"
},
```

Comment: The original issue is from angular-ui-tinymce. bower doesn't let you uninstall tinymce in this case, as angular-ui-tinymce is dependant upon it (error will be "bower ECONFLICT     angular-ui-tinymce depends on tinymce-dist").